# Keep menu open after selecting a item in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

My menu is closing after I click on my `toggleShare`button. How can i prevent this. I use angularJS with Angular material

Here is my code:

```
 <md-menu>
        <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
        </md-button>
        <md-menu-content>
            <md-menu-item>
              <md-button ng-click="toggleShare()"> 
              </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
```

Comment: Please provide detail code. Where is `toggleShare()` method? It will be better if you add any plnkr/fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `md-prevent-menu-close` attribute to stop menu from closing as suggested in [offical doc](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdMenu). Here is how you write code

```
<md-menu>
    <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content>
        <md-menu-item>
          <md-button ng-click="toggleShare()" md-prevent-menu-close="md-prevent-menu-close"> 
          </md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

Here is a working example of your desired result using this method. 
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/aNadYR

Comment: Note that this only works for `button` and `md-button` elements; it won't work if you are trying to use other content like checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above should be the accepted answer, but you can also use `ngMouseup` instead of `ngClick` and it works just the same :)

```
<md-menu>
  <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
  </md-button>
  <md-menu-content>
    <md-menu-item>
      <md-button ng-mouseup="toggleShare()"> 
       </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
  </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

Comment: This method works for all elements, no just button/md-button. Thanks for the tip!