# Angular 6 is setting my element to display: none

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

UPDATE:  This still happens even if I remove all references to the TS functions from the HTML template.  It happens even if I remove the contents of the SCSS classes `side-nav-submenu` and `submenu-open`.  However, it goes away if I remove the `side-nav-submenu` class from the `ul`.

I am trying to create a mobile side nav menu that is an unordered list containing buttons as list items, each of which is followed by another unordered list which is a submenu.  The submenu has `height: auto;` and `max-height: 0;`, with transition set on max-height and then I use that to make it expand and contract when the menu is toggled.

I am having a very weird and very specific bug.  If I open a submenu, then click one of its buttons (they currently do nothing), then click anything else, the submenu gets `style="display: none;"` set on it.  I can see this happen in real time in the dev tools.

I am baffled because there is nothing in my code which sets `display: none;` on these submenus.  I can only guess it's Angular doing it but I can't imagine why.  Here is my code.

**side-nav-mobile.component.html**

```
<ul [class.nav-active]="navOpen" class="side-nav-menu-mobile">
  <div (click)="toggleSubNav($event)">
    <li id="inv" class="side-nav-button">Inventory <span class="menu-arrow" [class.arrow-down]="subNavOpen['inv']">&#8250;</span></li>

    <ul class="side-nav-submenu">
      <li>Add An Item</li>
      <li>Inventory Search</li>
    </ul>

    <li id="cust" class="side-nav-button">Customers <span class="menu-arrow" [class.arrow-down]="subNavOpen['cust']">&#8250;</span></li>

    <ul class="side-nav-submenu">
      <li>Add New Customer</li>
      <li>Awaiting Action</li>
    </ul>

    <li id="trans" class="side-nav-button">Transactions <span class="menu-arrow" [class.arrow-down]="subNavOpen['trans']">&#8250;</span></li>

    <ul class="side-nav-submenu">
      <li>Bill Of Sale</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</ul>
```

**side-nav-mobile.component.scss**

```
@import "../../global-vars.scss";

.side-nav-menu-mobile {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: $page-background-color;
  left: -100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.side-nav-menu-mobile > div {
  margin-top: 3em;
}
.side-nav-menu-mobile > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.side-nav-menu-mobile li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
}
.side-nav-menu-mobile div > li {
  width: calc(100% - 1em);
  border-top: 1px solid $border-color;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $border-color;
}
.side-nav-submenu {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.15s linear;
  padding-left: 1em;

  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.submenu-open {
  // This is a horrible way to do this.
  // If something better ever comes along, implement.
  max-height: 8em;
}
.nav-active {
  left: 0;
}
.menu-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(0);
  transition: 0.15s ease-in;
}
.arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .side-nav-menu-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**side-nav-mobile.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-nav-mobile',
  templateUrl: './side-nav-mobile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-nav-mobile.component.scss']
})
export class SideNavMobileComponent implements OnInit {
  navOpen: boolean = false;
  subNavOpen: Object = {
    inv: false,
    cust: false,
    trans: false
  };

  toggleSlide(): void {
    this.navOpen = !this.navOpen;
  }

  toggleSubNav(event): void {
    if(event.target.className.indexOf("side-nav-button") == -1) {
      return;
    }
    if(event.target.nextElementSibling.className.indexOf("submenu-open") == -1) {
      event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add("submenu-open");
      this.subNavOpen[event.target.id] = true;
    } else {
      event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("submenu-open");
      this.subNavOpen[event.target.id] = false;
    }
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like another post solved this keep open style, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836044/keep-menu-open-after-selecting-a-item-in-angular

Comment: I'm not using material design, nor am I using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the `side-nav-submenu` class name was also used in the desktop side menu and this was conflicting somehow, because the desktop submenus were being set to `display: none` since we were on mobile.  Solved by changing the class name to `side-nav-mobile-submenu`.